# VHDL null file handle

Tags: vhdl

I have a procedure (testbench only, non-synthesisable) which receives data via an AXIS interface and writes it to a byte array. I also want the option to write the received data to file. To do this i've added a file handle such that any test bench using this procedure can declare a file handle and pass it to the procedure and the received data will be written to the given file via the file handle.

Here's the procedure declaration:

```
    procedure AXI_STREAM_RECEIVER
    ( 
        -- AXI-Stream Parameters
        variable PAYLOAD                : inout p_byte_array;
        constant SLAVE_READY_BEHAVE     : in    t_slave_ready_behave    := always_ready;
        constant READY_GAP_RANGE        : in    natural                 := 20;
        constant VERIFY_TKEEP           : in    boolean                 := false; 
        file     file_handle            : text;
        -- Interface Clock             
        signal   CLK                    : in    std_logic;
        -- Master/Slave I/O            
        signal   axis_tdata             : in    std_logic_vector;
        signal   axis_tkeep             : in    std_logic_vector;
        signal   axis_tvalid            : in    std_logic;
        signal   axis_tlast             : in    std_logic;
        signal   axis_tready            : out   std_logic;
        -- Misc.  
        constant VERIFY_TLAST           : in    boolean        := true;    
        constant VERBOSE                : in    boolean        := c_verbosity_default;
        constant DEBUG_SEVERITY_LEVEL   : in    severity_level := c_axil_debug_severity_level;
        constant DEBUG_PAYLOAD_CONTENT  : in    boolean        := false   
    );
```

As I want the write to file to be optional, I was hoping to be able to provide a 'null' file handle as a default when writing to file is not required. I've tried assigning a default but I get:

```
FILE interface declaration must not contain a default expression
```

Then i've tried assigning it to 'null' when instanced:

```
Illegal use of NULL literal.
```

But then if I leave it with no default and not assigned I get:

```
No feasible entries for subprogram "AXI_STREAM_RECEIVER"
```

Anybody know if it's possible to pass in some sort of null file descriptor?

Comment: A [mcve] would allow future readers to understand if the problem matches their own. Conditionally perform a FILE_OPEN call based on the file name not representing a null file. The value of the logical AND of a Status of type FILE_OPEN_STATUS = OPEN_OK and file_name /= null_file_name could allow conditional WRITEs. With only one mode out parameter the subprogram could be an impure function returning a value for axis_tready.

Comment: The subprogram body can be specified in the scope of the FILE, open status and constant declarations providing visibility inside the subprogram and allowing a reduced parameter list for readability. FILE_OPEN would conditionally be called externally with the benefit of not continually opening the FILE in APPEND_MODE followed by FILE_CLOSE prior to return. (Your procedure interface as shown has no parameter allowing conditional FILE_OPEN, if there is such a mechanism based on scope already it demonstrates the need for a [mcve].)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a [package with generics](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_major/#PackageGenerics) using VHDL-2008. The file handle and procedure are declared separately within the package header. Here's an example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library std;
use std.textio.all;

package gen_pkg is

  generic (
    PRINT_TO_FILE : boolean;
    FILE_NAME     : string;
    FILE_MODE     : file_open_kind := write_mode
  );

  file outfile : text;

  procedure TEST_PROCEDURE;

end gen_pkg;

package body gen_pkg is

  procedure TEST_PROCEDURE is
    variable outline : line;
  begin

    write(outline,string'("TEST STRING"));

    if PRINT_TO_FILE then
      file_open(outfile, FILE_NAME, FILE_MODE);
      writeline(outfile, outline);
      file_close(outfile);
    end if;

  end TEST_PROCEDURE;

end gen_pkg;
```

I've only shown a string being written, but use any of the overloaded variants of `write` in the `textio` package depending on your required datatype or you can use the VHDL-2008 function `to_string` which supports conversions of all types.

Then in your testbench, create a new instantiation of the package and access procedures/functions, etc. using the instantiation name:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library std;
use std.textio.all;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture arch of tb is

  package gp is new work.gen_pkg
  generic map (
    PRINT_TO_FILE => TRUE,
    FILE_NAME     => "./test_file.txt",
    FILE_MODE     => append_mode
  );

begin

  process begin
    for i in 0 to 4 loop
      gp.TEST_PROCEDURE;
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;

end arch;
```

Please note, if you write to the file more than once, like shown in this example, file mode must be `append_mode`. In `write_mode`, the file will be overwritten everytime `file_open` is called. If you only write to the file once per simulation, `write_mode` is fine. You can also have multiple new instantiations of your generic package in multiple locations, all writing to the same file, as along as they all use `append_mode` for the file mode.

[Here's](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4nYG) the working example on EDA playground setup to use Aldec Riviera Pro 2017.02. A login is required to run it. You must have pop-up blocker disabled in your browser in order to download the output file to inspect. The string "`TEST STRING`" should be written to the file 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL 2008 and earlier, you must always connect a file object in an interface list to another file object. Accessing the object when it is not open will cause an error, but there is no way to detect if the file is open or not. VHDL2019 does add a `FILE_STATE` function to do this, but I assume you still need to connect it to an existing file object with no defaults allowed.

Would it be easier to pass in a string of the filepath, which can have a default of ""? If it is a null string then dont open the file.

Comment: If your answer asks a question perhaps the problem wasn't clear enough for an answer?

Comment: There won't even be support for VHDL-2019 for another decade, right?

Comment: @user_007 Aldec have some VHDL-2019 support in their latest ActiveHDL and Riviera releases